# How to generate n independent normal random variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to this, and I'd like to know whether there's a function or any way I can generate n independent normal random variables in Matlab?

Comment: I know randn generates normally distributed random variable, but how do I know they are independent?

Answer (score 0):

`randn` will produce independent random variates from a Normal distribution.

In general, you have to trust that the sequence of variates produced by a pseudo-random number generator are statistically independent. Smart people who are experts in designing RNGs have worked hard to try to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two below,

```
randn
```

which will give you normally distributed random numbers.

```
rand
```

which will give you uniformly distributed random numbers.